# Can a primitive value be a type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Can a primitive value be a type in Typescript?

For instance, is this a valid type below? If it is not, how to make it valid?

```
export type Status = {
    completed: false;
}
```

Comment: Your type is actually valid as is. Here's an expanded example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgYwPYFswBsLGgXigbwFgAoKMqZNTbAEwC4oAzAQ3QGcIBuEgXxJNCQoAYVQYsuAiXIUx1CPSjAATgFcIvfsUHQAysGbBVbKHniVx2KAB8RciVuRw2wKAEtE97ADVWbxeZekviyVBKKLOzQfMROLu6eYdjwAG5+AYmWwaFZiirqUDxQAPTFSuDQEMrKSMpAA

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they can. The [TypeScript Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) show how setting a primitive literal can be used as the expected type, but using only one literal type isn't always valuable. Using your code as an example, you could use a type union to show possible literal values which could be assigned to `completed`:

```js
export type Status = {
    completed: false | 0 | "NO";
}
```

Comment: +1; conversely, it may be very valuable to have one branch of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) with a literal value, e.g. `{ completed: false, error: unknown } | { completed: true, value: unknown }`. See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggRgYygXigbygg9gWzAGwmAgBMAuKAMwEN8BnCAGiggCdWtWKBXAOwGteWAO68oAXygAfdJlwEipCsFbcmUAG601PAUNESA3AChjlPgmABLLGNYRqJeAgAU1RBWcBKdMaj+oK0ooN0QAOmw8QmISHzQ-AMTsXjosQjD8LABzUIQwrXw1LxNEyQh6aHjEpNtU9Myc9zy2DlZihP9xYy6gA).